# Centos 7 python update package python-2.7.5-80 rpm

Tags: centos, python, yum, upgrade, rpm

I am looking for this RPM `python-2.7.5-80.el7_6.x86_64.rpm` to address the security issue.  yum update not getting this package?

Any idea how to get this version of rpm for centos 7?

Thanks

**Update**

my **CentOS-Base.repo** file has below config

```
#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

This didn't find this package, I have created new file to get this update.

```
[update]
name=CentOS-$releasever - updates
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1
```

Comment: What repos are you pointing to? Perhaps it's simply not in those repos yet?

Comment: That version was just released by RHEL 4 days ago. Centos lags behind a bit.

Comment: my repo pointing to 'http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/cr/$basearch/' this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you posted in your last comment goes to an empty repository, not sure how that location got configured.  You may need to audit all of your configured YUM repositories to make sure they are pointing to the correct place.

The [package you are looking for can be found in the `updates` branch of the CentOS YUM repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-80.el7_6.x86_64.rpm)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have added my yum repo config in my original question.

Comment: I just noticed that the `cr` branch you posted in your comment is the Continuous Release branch, which comes from the installed `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo`, but is not enabled by default.

Comment: yeah, I enabled all these to get the updates `yum-config-manager --enable centosplus 
         yum-config-manager --enable extras
         yum-config-manager --enable cr `